# How to insert created_date of post 1 month using Timeuuid in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am developing a project for that I am using Cassandra for database. I am trying to insert a row with having datatype `timeuuid`. I want to achieve that with post 1 month date (add 1 month). 
I have no idea about it so anyone could you please help me about that?

Your help will be lot appreciated.

```
$created_date = new Cassandra\Timeuuid(); //add 1 month how?
```

Answer (score 0):

> TimeUUID Uses the time in 100 nanosecond intervals since 00:00:00.00 UTC (60
>   bits), a clock sequence number for prevention of duplicates (14 bits),
>   plus the IEEE 801 MAC address (48 bits) to generate a unique
>   identifier.

Based on your requirement I don't think timeuuid suits your requirement. You should use timestamp, so that you can process the logic at your java layer and store the value in cassandra.

For unique record you can use UUID data type.